# Any insight into Azure Dev Box for my situation?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-dev-box

Background: I am an Enterprise Developer with about 20 different solutions that are used throughout my organization.  The solutions range from custom Desktop Applications to Application Service Applications to Web Sites to iOS Applications.

Everything is developed using Visual Studio Enterprise, with several third party components/tools and a Mac for the iOS applications.

Software Distribution is very simple.  For the Desktop Applications and Service Applications I use ClickOnce where I publish to different file share locations, WebSites are published via copy to file share locations and the iOS Applications are published by uploading to Intune and using MDM and Line of Business Apps to iOS devices.

I would like to create a Microsoft Dev Box that could be used to handle all of this development.  I do not need a bunch of different Dev Boxes, I need one Dev Box that can do the same as my current development machine.  I am thinking of it as more of a Disaster Recovery option.

The Dev Box would need VS and third party tools, access to code repository and access to the internal network resources where software is published, very simple.

Is Dev Box a viable option or do I want something else?

Any thoughs or feedback would be much appreciated...